# There is a number of three digits, 1 is never immediate right of 2 is?

Tags: number-theory

There is a number of three digits, 1 is never immediate right of 2 is?
(A)771 (B) 791 (C) 881 (D)891. 
I faced this Question in Aptitude Competitive exam and don't know what the question actually means. Please anyone help me answering this question.

Comment: The language sounds off,  but if you want a guess I think it means that the block $21$ never occurs.  (I think "intermediate" should be "immediate").

Comment: Hint:  assuming that my reading is correct (not certain) then it is easier to count the three digit numbers in which the block $21$ does occur.

Comment: oh sorry I am Editting it again yes You are right sir

Comment: The question should be: "What is the amount of $3$-digit numbers not containing the sequence '21'?".

Comment: And the answer is $900-10-9=881$.

Comment: can you explain your answer please?

Answer (score 1):

We have total 900 three digit numbers from 100-999.

I think its typo it should be immediate.

We have numbers in which 1 is immediate right to 2 are 210-219, 121, 221, 321, 421, 521, 621, 721, 821, 921.

So we have numbers in which 1 is never immediate right of 2 = 900 - 19 = 881 numbers.

Comment: thank you so much sir..thank you..yes it is right

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)